# Equational reasoning with tying the knot

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation, continuations, tying-the-knot

I'm trying to wrap my head around Cont and callCC, by reducing this function:

```
s0 = (flip runContT) return $  do
    (k, n) <- callCC $ \k -> let f x = k (f, x)
                             in  return (f, 0)
    lift $ print n
    if n < 3
        then k (n+1) >> return ()
        else return ()
```

I've managed to reach this point:

```
s21 = runContT (let f x = ContT $ \_ -> cc (f, x) in ContT ($(f,0))) cc where
    cc = (\(k,n) -> let
        iff = if n < 3 then k (n+1) else ContT ($())
        in print n >> runContT iff (\_ -> return ()))
```

And at this point i have no idea what to do with recursive definition of `f`
What is the best way to finish this reduction?

Comment: I'd leave `f` defined as it is now, and start by expanding the `runContT`. Only unfold `f` when you must. By the way, I find the name `k` in `(k,n)<-...` to be confusing, since it looks as if it is the same as in `\k ->...` but these don't even have the same type (one takes an integer, the other one a pair).

Comment: @chi this is a little changed example from [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/jwiegley/understanding-continuations), but true, one of them could at least be called `k'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proceed as follows.

```
s21 = runContT (let f x = ContT $ \_ -> cc (f, x) in ContT ($(f,0))) cc where
    cc = (\(k,n) -> let
        iff = if n < 3 then k (n+1) else ContT ($())
        in print n >> runContT iff (\_ -> return ())

-- runContT is the opposite of ContT

s22 =  (let f x = ContT $ \_ -> cc (f, x) in ($(f,0))) cc
    where
    cc = (\(k,n) -> let
        iff = if n < 3 then k (n+1) else ContT ($())
        in print n >> runContT iff (\_ -> return ())

-- reordering

s23 = ($(f,0)) cc
    where
    f x = ContT $ \_ -> cc (f, x)
    cc = (\(k,n) -> let
        iff = if n < 3 then k (n+1) else ContT ($())
        in print n >> runContT iff (\_ -> return ())

s24 = cc (f,0)
    where ...

-- beta

s25 = let iff = if 0 < 3 then f (0+1) else ContT ($())
       in print 0 >> runContT iff (\_ -> return ())
    where ...

-- if, arithmetics

s26 = let iff = f 1
       in print 0 >> runContT iff (\_ -> return ())
    where ...

s27 = print 0 >> runContT (f 1) (\_ -> return ())
    where ...

s28 = print 0 >> runContT (ContT $ \_ -> cc (f, 1)) (\_ -> return ())
    where ...

s29 = print 0 >> (\_ -> cc (f, 1)) (\_ -> return ())
    where ...

s30 = print 0 >> cc (f, 1)
    where ...

-- repeat all the steps s24..s30

s31 = print 0 >> print 1 >> cc (f, 2)
    where ...

-- etc.

s32 = print 0 >> print 1 >> print 2 >> cc (f, 3)
    where ...

s33 = print 0 >> print 1 >> print 2 >>
      let iff = if 3 < 3 then f (3+1) else ContT ($())
       in print 3 >> runContT iff (\_ -> return ())
    where ...

s34 = print 0 >> print 1 >> print 2 >> print 3 >> 
      let iff = ContT ($())
       in runContT iff (\_ -> return ()))
    where ...

s35 = print 0 >> print 1 >> print 2 >> print 3 >> 
      runContT (ContT ($())) (\_ -> return ())
    where ...

s36 = print 0 >> print 1 >> print 2 >> print 3 >> 
      ($()) (\_ -> return ())
    where ...

s37 = print 0 >> print 1 >> print 2 >> print 3 >> 
      return ()
```

Comment: Looks like i didn't notice that i can bring `runContT` into `in ContT ($(f,0))`, thanks